# Can I sue my friend for stealing money from my personal bank acct.?

Tags: texas

My best friend of many years and I went into business together. I bought a franchise for him and I. In the Franchise agreement it is required to submit a bank acct. that is currently open, active etc.. I submitted my personal bank acct. to the franchiser to enter into the contract. With that being done my business partner/friend had access to this bank acct. information being it was in our mutual contract. We use this bank acct until "we" open a business bank acct.. My partner decided to open a bank acct. at the same bank my acct. was at. I discovered he was doing telephone withdrawals to his new acct. The way I knew it was his he used my address for his bank correspondence, knowing I would not open his mail. I later found out he did this to keep his girlfriend from knowing of this money. We are no longer friends and were getting out of our business.
What are my legal rights to get my money back? Of course he denies everything. He stole 20,220.00.
Thanks A.B. Ford

Comment: See a lawyer. We cant answer questions seeing legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - hire a lawyer to find out how.

Comment: Surely a more helpful answer is possible.

Comment: @phoog yes, and the lawyer should give it

Comment: Just in case the poster reads this very short answer and thinks it's not much help - it is _exactly_ the right answer and tells you exactly what to do.